# How to install mathpazo correctly from TeX Live Manager?

Tags: texlive, mathpazo

I've just installed [BasicTeX 2013](http://www.tug.org/mactex/morepackages.html), which is the MacTeX equivalent of the TeX Live "small" scheme.

Using TeX Live Utility (MacTeX's GUI for `tlmgr`), I've installed `mathpazo`, but a minimal example

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathpazo}
\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

yields the error: (after the usual Metafont complaints)

```
./small.tex:3: Font OT1/ppl/m/n/10=pplr7t at 10.0pt not loadable: Metric (TFM) 
file not found.
```

After installing the `palatino` package, this error goes away, but a slightly less minimal example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[osf]{mathpazo}
\begin{document}
hello 123
\end{document}
```

Now yields the less promising:

```
!pdfTeX error: /usr/texbin/pdflatex (file fplrc8a.pfb): cannot open Type 1 font
 file for reading
 ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

Uh oh. I'm stuck for ideas for what to try next.

Comment: Just a guess: (http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/fpl) has the file `fplrc8a.pfb`. Besides compiling your second example on a full tex-live also `urw/palatino/uplr8a.pfb` is embedded, and I think this is from (http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/urw/base35) which perhaps already is in BasicTeX (I didn't try out BasicTeX).

Comment: I see that that `fpl` is part of the `collection-fontsrecommended` collection on TL2013, which can be installed from TexLiveUtility on the Mac. I know that BasicTeX already contains the Latin Modern from this collection, I have no idea (not having tried) about the Base35 fonts.

Comment: The explanation is perhaps that the required `psnfss` bundle provides the `fpls.map` file which contains the correspondance from `pplrc8r` (to which `mathpazo` leads via the virtual font `pplr9o.vf`) to the `fplrc8a.pfb` file; but the latter is provided in the `fpl` package which is not included in `psnfss` but must be installed additionally. (as far as I can tell).

Comment: http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/required/psnfss/00readme.txt seems to be relevant, particularly the section _Fonts required for PSNFSS_

Comment: @jfbu — thanks; if you add an answer below I'll mark it as correct `:)`

Comment: your answer tells it all! I will upvote it...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `mathpazo` package implicitly requires the Palladio set of fonts, which are not part of the standard `psnfss` package.

Therefore, it is also necessary to install the `fpl` package, as well as `palatino`, before `mathpazo` will work.

(Thanks to @jfbu for the tip!)